# How FOR XML Works in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xpath, sqlxml

Can somebody explain how is FOR XML used in SQL Server? Is this the only way to concatenate strings by rows without using an user-defined function? I got it from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server), did what I need to do, but I don't understand it.

The person who posted this did not explain anything. After an exhaustive 
search I couldn't find anything understandable. And no, MSDN was not helpful given my limited SQL skills.

Here's the my SQL, with only the names changed from the one in that post.

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ' -' + Code
    FROM #Z 
    WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,''
 ) AS ConcatCode
FROM #Z Results
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: MSDN's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) seems to be pretty clear. It's even more clear how to use `PATH` mode [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx).

Comment: That particular use of `FOR XML XPATH` is one of the [hacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server) to do GROUP_CONCAT or ListAgg in Sql Server.

Comment: Well I don't know about attributes, elements, or XPath expressions. That sounds more like HTML lingo.

Comment: `XML` is quite similar to `HTML`; they both use attributes, elements, and can have XPath queries run against them. What **specific question** would you like us to answer for you here? We don't do tutorials.

Comment: it could be the [TYPE directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms190025.aspx) that is confusing things for you. Basically, it is specifying that an xml data type should be returned. Then [.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms178030.aspx) is a method that acts on that datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the only way to concatenate strings by rows without using an user-defined function?

This is the simplest method to concatenate rows

> how FOR XML is used in SQL Server

I suppose examples below will give more or less clear understanding how use it

```
------------------------------------------------------------
--Create temp table for testing
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Z') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Z
CREATE TABLE #Z
    (
      ID INT ,
      SomeText VARCHAR(3)
    )
INSERT  INTO #Z
        ( ID, SomeText )
VALUES  ( 1, 'AAA' ),
        ( 2, 'BBB' ),
        ( 3, 'CCC' ),
        ( 1, 'ZZZ' ),
        ( 1, 'XXX' ),
        ( 2, 'YYY' )
------------------------------------------------------------
--1. Concatenate
SELECT  SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ',' + SomeText
                    FROM    #Z
                  FOR
                    XML PATH('')
                  ), 2, 1000) AS Concatenated
------------------------------------------------------------
--2. Concatenate for each ID
SELECT DISTINCT
        Z_out.id ,
        SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ',' + SomeText
                    FROM    #Z AS Z_in
                    WHERE   Z_in.ID = Z_out.id
                  FOR
                    XML PATH('')
                  ), 2, 1000) AS Concatenated
FROM    #Z AS Z_out
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Some questions, 1) Why use substring? 2) Why take in ' ' as parameter for XML PATH function?

Comment: 1) substring used to remove first comma 2) If you provide an empty string (FOR XML PATH ('')), no wrapper element is generated. For more information use this   link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx